# Wordpress do_shortcode() with post_content

Tags: wordpress

I want to make the title of any post from post content. So, I made the following in functions.php

```
 function my_title($title)   
 {  
    global $post;       
    // Do whatever here with your title...  
    $content = $post->post_content;
    print $content;       

    $title =$content.  $post->post_title . ' | ' .  
    get_bloginfo('name');     

    return $title;  
}
```

It prints shortcode inside post content but if i apply `$content = do_shortcode( $content );` it does not produce the actual post content. When i applied `$content = do_shortcode( $content );` website hanged. Let me know how to use `$content = do_shortcode( $content );` inside this function so that title can be changed.

Comment: What is `$var` here? And what is use of `do_shortcode` here? can you explain what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @SudharshanNair it was a mistake I have edited the post. $var was mistyped. I am getting problem when it invoke $content = do_shortcode( $content ); When I print $content it shows the shortcode present on the page but if this is passed as a argument in do_shortcode(), I am getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this with [wp_filter_nohtml_kses](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_filter_nohtml_kses/). I guess your html o/p is causing the issue

```
$content = $post->post_content;
$content = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $content ); // this wp_filter_nohtml_kses indicates strip_tags
$content = do_shortcode( $content );
```

or

```
echo do_shortcode(get_post_field('post_content', $post->id));
```

Comment: @NARAYANCHANGDER. Atleast you can trace error and find out, what is causing issue actually by setting `WP_DEBUG` to true

Comment: yes I found the error "PHP Fatal error:  ob_start(): Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in C:\xampp\htdocs\WP\wp-content\plugins\mtouch-quiz\mtouchquiz.php on line 573". Any Idea how to fix it?

Comment: Hi I have got the code to change SEO title  from http://biostall.com/override-wordpress-all-in-one-seo-pack-plugin-on-certain-pages/   Could you please check why I am unable to extract post content in that function? It would be a great help. I am looking for solution last few months but no luck.

Comment: @NARAYANCHANGDER Please post new question for this